# find maximum id based on sequence spacing

Tags: r

say we have data.frame 'a'

```
set.seed(666)
a <- data.frame( x= rnorm(9), y=letters[1:9] , id=c(1111:1117,1119,1121))
```

I want to be able to find the maximum 'id' value before ids start increasing by '2' instead of '1' and keep all data up to and including that 'id' for a this would be:

```
#> a
#           x y   id
#1  0.7533110 a 1111
#2  2.0143547 b 1112
#3 -0.3551345 c 1113
#4  2.0281678 d 1114
#5 -2.2168745 e 1115
#6  0.7583962 f 1116
#7 -1.3061853 g 1117
```

Comment: What do you mean by *maximum id*?  They're all different.  It seems like `a[c(1, diff(a$id)) == 1, ]` might do it

Comment: I mean the last value before the increments become 2

Answer (score 1):

I might use `rle()` to find out how long the first run of differences between IDs is equal to one. For example

```
stopat <- with(rle(diff(a$id)), if(values[1]==1) lengths[1]+1 else 1)
a[1:stopat, ]

           x y   id
1  0.7533110 a 1111
2  2.0143547 b 1112
3 -0.3551345 c 1113
4  2.0281678 d 1114
5 -2.2168745 e 1115
6  0.7583962 f 1116
7 -1.3061853 g 1117
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `diff` and `match`:

```
> a[1:match(2, diff(a$id)),]
#           x y   id
#1  0.7533110 a 1111
#2  2.0143547 b 1112
#3 -0.3551345 c 1113
#4  2.0281678 d 1114
#5 -2.2168745 e 1115
#6  0.7583962 f 1116
#7 -1.3061853 g 1117
```

If the difference is not necessarily equals to 2, you can proceed with:

```
a[1:match(TRUE, diff(a$id)>1),]
```